# Is there a list of all the binaries produced by glibc and is there a way to choose what binaries you want to build?

Tags: compilation, glibc

I have searched through the glibc documentation and I have asked in various other places but all I can find is that it produces [200+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/394328) binaries.

Comment: What do you mean "binaries produced by glibc"?

Comment: Big picture, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @PeterSW the shared libraries (.so files).

Comment: @NovaDenizen I am using a very slow machine and compiling glibc as a whole takes a very long time. I am trying to make a linux distribution with a different directory structure and since there is no straight forward way to do this, I must modify hardcoded paths,compile and test repeatedly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're building on a slow machine you might want to disable gcc's optimization.  Go into `config.make` and get rid of the `-O2` flag.

I just did a configure and build of the current 2.19 stable glibc and here are all 278 `.so` files it generated.

```
./iconvdata/IBM16804.so
./iconvdata/IBM500.so
./iconvdata/IBM1046.so
./iconvdata/SJIS.so
./iconvdata/CP1252.so
./iconvdata/IBM1162.so
./iconvdata/CP773.so
./iconvdata/JOHAB.so
./iconvdata/IBM284.so
./iconvdata/CP1258.so
./iconvdata/IBM932.so
./iconvdata/libJIS.so
./iconvdata/IBM1364.so
./iconvdata/EBCDIC-FI-SE-A.so
./iconvdata/EBCDIC-AT-DE.so
./iconvdata/IBM1388.so
./iconvdata/MAC-IS.so
./iconvdata/IBM871.so
./iconvdata/ISO-2022-KR.so
./iconvdata/UHC.so
./iconvdata/EBCDIC-CA-FR.so
./iconvdata/IBM1160.so
./iconvdata/IBM943.so
./iconvdata/IBM856.so
./iconvdata/EBCDIC-IS-FRISS.so
./iconvdata/ISO8859-3.so
./iconvdata/KOI8-T.so
./iconvdata/BRF.so
./iconvdata/IBM875.so
./iconvdata/ISO8859-6.so
./iconvdata/IBM852.so
./iconvdata/ARMSCII-8.so
./iconvdata/ISO8859-9E.so
./iconvdata/IBM933.so
./iconvdata/CP1125.so
./iconvdata/ISO8859-7.so
./iconvdata/IBM280.so
./iconvdata/IBM860.so
./iconvdata/CP1250.so
./iconvdata/EBCDIC-ES-A.so
./iconvdata/EBCDIC-AT-DE-A.so
./iconvdata/CP1256.so
./iconvdata/ANSI_X3.110.so
./iconvdata/CP771.so
./iconvdata/IBM4899.so
./iconvdata/NATS-DANO.so
./iconvdata/IBM861.so
./iconvdata/IEC_P27-1.so
./iconvdata/TSCII.so
./iconvdata/GREEK-CCITT.so
./iconvdata/IBM905.so
./iconvdata/INIS-CYRILLIC.so
./iconvdata/EBCDIC-DK-NO.so
./iconvdata/ASMO_449.so
./iconvdata/IBM256.so
./iconvdata/IBM1008_420.so
./iconvdata/IBM1097.so
./iconvdata/IBM937.so
./iconvdata/IBM903.so
./iconvdata/ISO_6937-2.so
./iconvdata/UTF-16.so
./iconvdata/CP774.so
./iconvdata/libISOIR165.so
./iconvdata/IBM281.so
./iconvdata/HP-ROMAN9.so
./iconvdata/ISO8859-4.so
./iconvdata/EBCDIC-IT.so
./iconvdata/GREEK7.so
./iconvdata/EBCDIC-DK-NO-A.so
./iconvdata/MAC-UK.so
./iconvdata/GBGBK.so
./iconvdata/SAMI-WS2.so
./iconvdata/GEORGIAN-PS.so
./iconvdata/VISCII.so
./iconvdata/IBM891.so
./iconvdata/IBM1137.so
./iconvdata/IBM1155.so
./iconvdata/IBM1164.so
./iconvdata/IBM1390.so
./iconvdata/RK1048.so
./iconvdata/IBM273.so
./iconvdata/ISO-2022-CN.so
./iconvdata/IBM285.so
./iconvdata/ISO8859-10.so
./iconvdata/KOI8-RU.so
./iconvdata/INIS.so
./iconvdata/IBM420.so
./iconvdata/ISO-2022-CN-EXT.so
./iconvdata/IBM423.so
./iconvdata/IBM038.so
./iconvdata/ISO8859-5.so
./iconvdata/CP10007.so
./iconvdata/CP737.so
./iconvdata/IBM1133.so
./iconvdata/IBM1141.so
./iconvdata/GBBIG5.so
./iconvdata/IBM1167.so
./iconvdata/KOI8-R.so
./iconvdata/IBM1149.so
./iconvdata/INIS-8.so
./iconvdata/ISO8859-9.so
./iconvdata/IBM278.so
./iconvdata/KOI8-U.so
./iconvdata/IBM866NAV.so
./iconvdata/HP-ROMAN8.so
./iconvdata/IBM864.so
./iconvdata/IBM1124.so
./iconvdata/IBM1154.so
./iconvdata/IBM904.so
./iconvdata/IBM1132.so
./iconvdata/IBM1145.so
./iconvdata/EBCDIC-FR.so
./iconvdata/EBCDIC-ES.so
./iconvdata/IBM902.so
./iconvdata/ISO_6937.so
./iconvdata/IBM274.so
./iconvdata/UTF-32.so
./iconvdata/EBCDIC-FI-SE.so
./iconvdata/IBM1166.so
./iconvdata/BIG5HKSCS.so
./iconvdata/IBM4517.so
./iconvdata/IBM1142.so
./iconvdata/IBM935.so
./iconvdata/IBM1130.so
./iconvdata/EBCDIC-US.so
./iconvdata/IBM12712.so
./iconvdata/ISO8859-8.so
./iconvdata/EUC-JP-MS.so
./iconvdata/CWI.so
./iconvdata/IBM4909.so
./iconvdata/LATIN-GREEK-1.so
./iconvdata/IBM939.so
./iconvdata/ISO_11548-1.so
./iconvdata/IBM1026.so
./iconvdata/HP-TURKISH8.so
./iconvdata/MIK.so
./iconvdata/IBM1399.so
./iconvdata/IBM297.so
./iconvdata/ISO-2022-JP.so
./iconvdata/CSN_369103.so
./iconvdata/IBM851.so
./iconvdata/ISO8859-1.so
./iconvdata/IBM921.so
./iconvdata/CP772.so
./iconvdata/UNICODE.so
./iconvdata/MAC-SAMI.so
./iconvdata/EBCDIC-ES-S.so
./iconvdata/CP1255.so
./iconvdata/IBM1371.so
./iconvdata/GBK.so
./iconvdata/PT154.so
./iconvdata/IBM1129.so
./iconvdata/CP775.so
./iconvdata/EUC-JP.so
./iconvdata/EUC-JISX0213.so
./iconvdata/HP-GREEK8.so
./iconvdata/CP1257.so
./iconvdata/libKSC.so
./iconvdata/libCNS.so
./iconvdata/IBM290.so
./iconvdata/IBM930.so
./iconvdata/TCVN5712-1.so
./iconvdata/IBM901.so
./iconvdata/IBM1153.so
./iconvdata/IBM1157.so
./iconvdata/IBM1146.so
./iconvdata/EBCDIC-UK.so
./iconvdata/IBM850.so
./iconvdata/IBM1144.so
./iconvdata/IBM437.so
./iconvdata/ISO8859-2.so
./iconvdata/IBM1156.so
./iconvdata/IBM1047.so
./iconvdata/GB18030.so
./iconvdata/ISO8859-13.so
./iconvdata/IBM855.so
./iconvdata/IBM275.so
./iconvdata/MACINTOSH.so
./iconvdata/ISO646.so
./iconvdata/IBM1158.so
./iconvdata/ISO8859-14.so
./iconvdata/EBCDIC-PT.so
./iconvdata/NATS-SEFI.so
./iconvdata/EUC-CN.so
./iconvdata/IBM1140.so
./iconvdata/ISO-2022-JP-3.so
./iconvdata/GREEK7-OLD.so
./iconvdata/EUC-TW.so
./iconvdata/LATIN-GREEK.so
./iconvdata/IBM1147.so
./iconvdata/CP770.so
./iconvdata/DEC-MCS.so
./iconvdata/IBM1148.so
./iconvdata/GOST_19768-74.so
./iconvdata/CP1254.so
./iconvdata/ISO8859-11.so
./iconvdata/MAC-CENTRALEUROPE.so
./iconvdata/IBM9448.so
./iconvdata/IBM1123.so
./iconvdata/IBM4971.so
./iconvdata/ISO8859-15.so
./iconvdata/ISO-IR-209.so
./iconvdata/IBM1143.so
./iconvdata/IBM922.so
./iconvdata/IBM869.so
./iconvdata/IBM880.so
./iconvdata/IBM1161.so
./iconvdata/BIG5.so
./iconvdata/IBM866.so
./iconvdata/CP932.so
./iconvdata/IBM918.so
./iconvdata/ISO-IR-197.so
./iconvdata/IBM868.so
./iconvdata/IBM865.so
./iconvdata/IBM870.so
./iconvdata/T.61.so
./iconvdata/libJISX0213.so
./iconvdata/IBM1008.so
./iconvdata/IBM5347.so
./iconvdata/ISO8859-16.so
./iconvdata/ISO_10367-BOX.so
./iconvdata/IBM9066.so
./iconvdata/IBM037.so
./iconvdata/KOI-8.so
./iconvdata/IBM9030.so
./iconvdata/IBM1122.so
./iconvdata/ISO_2033.so
./iconvdata/IBM424.so
./iconvdata/EUC-KR.so
./iconvdata/IBM874.so
./iconvdata/ECMA-CYRILLIC.so
./iconvdata/SHIFT_JISX0213.so
./iconvdata/ISIRI-3342.so
./iconvdata/IBM277.so
./iconvdata/IBM803.so
./iconvdata/GEORGIAN-ACADEMY.so
./iconvdata/IBM1163.so
./iconvdata/IBM1025.so
./iconvdata/IBM1004.so
./iconvdata/TIS-620.so
./iconvdata/IBM863.so
./iconvdata/HP-THAI8.so
./iconvdata/IBM862.so
./iconvdata/IBM857.so
./iconvdata/ISO_5427.so
./iconvdata/IBM1112.so
./iconvdata/ISO_5428.so
./iconvdata/ISO_5427-EXT.so
./iconvdata/UTF-7.so
./iconvdata/CP1251.so
./iconvdata/libGB.so
./iconvdata/CP1253.so
./elf/sotruss-lib.so
./elf/ld.so
./rt/librt.so
./math/libm.so
./locale/libBrokenLocale.so
./libidn/libcidn.so
./login/libutil.so
./malloc/libmemusage.so
./resolv/libanl.so
./resolv/libresolv.so
./resolv/libnss_dns.so
./crypt/libcrypt.so
./hesiod/libnss_hesiod.so
./nis/libnss_compat.so
./nis/libnss_nis.so
./nis/libnsl.so
./nis/libnss_nisplus.so
./nptl/libpthread.so
./nptl_db/libthread_db.so
./nss/libnss_db.so
./nss/libnss_files.so
./libc.so
./debug/libSegFault.so
./debug/libpcprofile.so
./linkobj/libc.so
./dlfcn/libdl.so
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer, Please give this man/woman some points.

Comment: @thenaglecode I didn't know I had to click the "points" button, I thought I just had to accept the answer.